# Lua-cURL specified module could not be found

Tags: lua, libcurl

I tried compiling Lua-cURLv3 from:

https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3

I tried installing it with luarocks. My Luarocks currently uses Lua 5.2. It was able to compile and install the lcurl.dll file. But if I do require("lcurl") it gives me an error saying

`error loading module 'lcurl' from file lcurl.dll: 
         The specified module could not be found`

I am running this on a Windows 10 machine. I also tried compiling the whole project with CodeBlocks using Lua 5.3 but I receive the same error.
       I cannot see why it is giving this error. If anyone can help me resolve this I would be grateful.

Comment: sorry. If it found dll then path correct. then checkout export function in lcurl it should be luaopen_lcurl.

Comment: you caa find binary rock (but only for Lua 51) on AppVeyor https://ci.appveyor.com/project/moteus/lua-curlv3/build/0.3.2.6/job/2po6l4pmgwd8gy3k/artifacts

Comment: also check that libcurl.dll in path and it can be found

Comment: Thanks for the help. It finally worked. It worked with the libcurl.dll of the nossl option. It compiled fine but did not work if I used other versions of libcurl.dll

Comment: may be you have no openssl dll in path. You can try use sudo of deps walker. I use plagin for Total Commander.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It was not able to find ssleay32.dll. Now it works fine.